# Junit mockito when(..).thenReturn() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Can anyone explain me the below scenario
Code to be tested 
UserTransaction.java

```
@Override
public ServiceResponse<User> get(String name) {
    ServiceResponse<User> response = new ServiceResponse<User>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> exp = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("expression", "eq");
    map.put("property", "name");
    map.put("value", name);
    exp.add(map);
    List<User> users = userDao.getByCriteria(exp);
    if (!users.isEmpty()) {
        response.setResponse(users.get(0));
    } else {
        response.setResponse(null);
    }
    return response;
}
```

UserDao.java

```
public List<User> getByCriteria(List<Map<String, Object>> exp) {
  DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
  for (Integer i=0;i<exp.size();i++){
    String expression = (String) exp.get(i).get("expression");
    String property = (String) exp.get(i).get("property");
    if(expression.equals("eq"){
       criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(property,exp.get(i).get("value")));
    }
  }
  return hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
 }
```

UserTransactionTest.java

```
private UserTransaction userTransactions = new UserTransaction();
private UserDao userDao = mock(UserDao.class);

@Test
public void testGet() {
   User user = new User();
   user.setName("Raman");
    try {
        when(userDao.getByCriteria(anyList())).thenReturn(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ServiceResponse<User> response = userTransactions.get("raman");
    User result = response.getResponse();
    assertEquals("Raman", result.getName());
    assertEquals(0, response.getErrors().size());
}
```

works fine.

But instead of "anyList()" I passed a user-defined list "myList"

```
List<Map<String,Object>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("expression","eq");
map.put("property","name");
map.put("value","raman");
myList.add(map);
when(userTransactions.getByCriteria(myList)).thenReturn(user);
```

Throws `NullPointerException` at the line `assertEquals()`. Why? What actually happens if `anyList()` is given?

Comment: You're not posting enough code making it difficult for others to see where you are going wrong. Is `when(userTransactions.` a spelling mistake? How is `myList` being created? what is the method signature of `getByCriteria()`?

Comment: Am I missing something here? You keep posting `when(userTransactions...` and that object has not been created. You have created `userTransaction` in your code above but not `userTransactions` (note the "s" on the end). If you debug your code does an object named `userTransactions` exist and it it a mocked object?

Comment: Can you clarify whether it's throwing the exception on the line with `when`, or on the line within the test where `getByCriteria` is actually called?  And post some more of your code - as others have said, you haven't really provided enough information to make it possible for us to diagnose what's wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you've already solved your problem by now, but in case anyone stumbles upon the same issue, here's the answer:

In the code you've provided, you are not using the mocked `myList` you've created. The `get()` method always calls `userDao.getByCriteria(exp)`, a local variable.

This is why `anyList()` works, while `myList` doesn't.

If you **do** want to test the expression, `List<Map<String,Object>> exp` should be a member of your class, not a local variable:

```
public class UserTransaction {
    private List<Map<String,Object>> exp;

    public UserTransaction() {
        // creating a default exp value
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("expression", "eq");
        map.put("property", "name");
        map.put("value", name);
        exp.add(map);
    }

    // getters and setters for exp

    public ServiceResponse<User> get(String name) {
        ServiceResponse<User> response = new ServiceResponse<User>();
        List<User> users = userDao.getByCriteria(exp);
        if (!users.isEmpty()) {
            response.setResponse(users.get(0));
        } else {
            response.setResponse(null);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

And in your Test:

```
private UserTransaction userTransactions = new UserTransaction();
private UserDao userDao = mock(UserDao.class);

@Test
public void testGet() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Raman");

    // creating a custom expression
    List<Map<String,Object>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("expression","eq");
    map.put("property","name");
    map.put("value","raman");
    myList.add(map);

    // replacing exp with the list created
    userTransactions.setExp(myList);
    // return user when calling getByCriteria(myList)
    when(userDao.getByCriteria(myList)).thenReturn(user);

    ServiceResponse<User> response = userTransactions.get("raman");
    User result = response.getResponse();
    assertEquals("Raman", result.getName());
    assertEquals(0, response.getErrors().size());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your code is complete (I suspect it may not be) then you haven't specified the mock object that contains the `get()` method. This should be present in the call to `when(...)`

I am expecting code like this...

```
UserDao mockDao = mock(UserDao.class);

when(mockDao.get(list)).thenReturn(users);
```

Comment: I have did as above. But the problem is when i pass anyList() as parameter the test is passed but when I pass a userdefined "list" it throws Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think anyList() is a method which you are mocking and list is not a method , can you please post the source code for whatever you are writing this test case

Comment: anyList() is a matcher method in Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not testing UserDao.

Next, anyList() produce mockito matcher and you should pass matcher to userDao.getByCriteria in order to do something, so, you should use Matchers.same(your list) or Matchers.eq(your list).

Exception appear because by default Mockito creats nice mock and by default they returning null on any unexpected method invocation.